# Lifecycle componentWillReceiveProps is called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been implementing [Tyler McGinnis curriculum](https://github.com/ReactjsProgram/react-fundamentals-curriculum) to learn react.

It's a weather app. And i'm having trouble debugging a strange behaviour. I'm pretty sure it's something silly that i'm doing or i might have missed an information piece of information.

`SearchContainer` is a ParentContainer,

```
var React = require("react");
var Search = require("../components/Search");

var SearchContainer = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    formType: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      formType: "form"
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      city: ""
    }
  },
  handleSearchSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.push('/forecast/' + this.state.city);
  },
  handleCityChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      city: e.target.value
    });
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Search
        formType={this.props.formType}
        city={this.state.city}
        onCityChange={this.handleCityChange}
        onSearchSubmit={this.handleSearchSubmit}/>
    );
  }
})

module.exports = SearchContainer;
```

`SearchContainer` changes Context and switches to `ForecastContainer`,

```
var React = require("react");

var Forecast = require("../components/Forecast");
var Api = require("../helpers/Api");

var ForecastContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      data: []
    }
  },
  makeRequest: function(city) {
    this.setState({
          isLoading: true,
    });
    Api.getDayForecast(city).then( function(data) {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: data.data.list
        });
    }.bind(this) );
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.makeRequest(this.props.params.city);
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    this.makeRequest(newProps.params.city);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Forecast isLoading={this.state.isLoading} data={this.state.data} />
    )
  }
});

module.exports = ForecastContainer;
```

Now here, `componentWillReceiveProps` is called twice. I don't understand why. Technically it should be just called once. I'm updating state in `MakeRequest` method. It's called second time after state change.

I'm also enclosing screenshots for better understanding of Application flow.

[image]

**Update:**

I was using React-Router version 3.0.3. Downgrading to 2.0.0 fixes it. Which is all the more strange.

Comment: So i just downgraded react-router version to 2.0.0 and now the componentWillReceiveProps is called once. This is strange. Is it something related to new React-Router?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* it is called twice, but I can tell you that it should not matter. The problem is that you're not comparing the props for what has changed. If you do this, the code will behave the way you want:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
  if (newProps.params.city !== this.props.params.city) {
    this.makeRequest(newProps.params.city);
  }
},
```

See also the official ReactJS documentation, which states (emphasis mine):
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

> Note that React may call this method even if the props have not
>   changed, so **make sure to compare the current and next values** if you
>   only want to handle changes. This may occur when the parent component
>   causes your component to re-render.

Comment: Oh yes that's what i thought. I did a comparison and went ahead with it. I don't know why i'm being finicky about this. It's just funny how it also works just by downgrading react-router version.

Comment: @kishanio My guess is that the new router for some reason causes one of the re-renders mentioned in the docs. However it is *allowed* behavior and not a bug, so I'd go back to router v3.0.3 if there is no compelling reason not to.

Comment: @Lucero Worked perfect!  I was having a very tough time finding a way to restrict it.